# Можно ли понять, под каким именем сайт хостится в интернете?

Tags: windows, веб-программирование, iis

Допустим, есть сервер и на нем хостится через IIS сайт.

Можно ли как-нибудь получить информацию о том, под каким URL этот сайт отображается в интернете?

Comment: Логи, например?

Comment: В общем случае нельзя. Но если всё устроено без затей, то сам сайт всегда видит url запроса.

Comment: @Sergey и в каком месте это можно посмотреть на сервере?

Comment: @iluxa1810 надо смотреть API сервера. Или CGI, который если и не  поддерживается прямо, но имеет свои отголоски в API сервера http://www.firststeps.ru/cgi/r.php?7